# Pretty printing 2d array in racket

Tags: racket

How to pretty print the contents of the 2d array b?
The code below only returns:

```
#<array:srfi-9-record-type-descriptor>


(require srfi/25)
(require racket/pretty)

(define (board x y)
  (make-array (shape 0 x 0 y) 0))

(define b (board 7 7))
(pretty-print b)
```

also tried:

(array-map (lambda (n) (print n)) b)  ...(i'm trying to mark this as code but it doesn't work)

but it returns:
 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

is there any way for the print to insert a new line every x characters?

Answer (score 2):

You can try rolling your own pretty-printing procedure, give this a try:

```
(define (pretty-print board)
  (for ((i (in-range (array-length board 0))))
    (for ((j (in-range (array-length board 1))))
      (printf "~a\t" (array-ref board i j)))
    (newline)))
```

For example:

```
(pretty-print (board 3 3))

0   0   0   
0   0   0   
0   0   0
```